# Can ghast fireballs break glass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm thinking about building some glass structures in the Nether on my friends' SMP server (once 1.6 is released), and haven't spent enough time in SP to determine this for myself since I like to work on the SMP server... so, can Ghast fireballs break glass?  I intend to make fully-enclosed structures that are too small for Ghasts to spawn inside of, but I want to make sure that an errant Ghast fireball fired while someone's outside won't end up destroying my structure.

I checked the [wiki entry on glass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass), and it discusses arrows and spider jockey arrows, but nothing about Ghast fireballs.

Comment: your only chances are playing on peaceful or building with stone first and replacing that with glass quickly one block at a time. oh, or you could change your (and maybe the server's official) texture pack to make something stable like brick transparent as "robust glass"

Comment: A good thing to use for windows in the nether is iron bars, or nether fence posts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The minimum [block resistance](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Block_Resistance) required to absorb all blast force of the Ghast's fireballs is 16.42, so less resistant blocks may be destroyed in a fireball explosion depending on exactly where it hits.

Stone, cobblestone, stone slabs, brick, and other "robust" blocks will be unaffected as they all have resistances of 30, but glass only has a resistance of 1.5, so will be destroyed easily.

Comment: A fireball is listed on that page as having a blast radius of 1.5m, so if a fireball exploded against a stone block adjacent to a glass block, it could theoretically break the glass, correct? (edited because the link had some info on another thing I was wondering about)

Comment: Well please update the number 20.17 (to 16.42) because it was wrongly deduced.

Comment: @xfs where's that number from?  Mine is from the Minecraft wiki...

Comment: he wrong value and the updated value are all deduced by me. Check the talk page of that article ("Fireballs vs Furnaces") for why 20.17 is wrong and 16.42 is right. (After some googling, oh my God what a mistake I made.)

Answer (score 15):

I believe that ghasts do not shoot at you through glass, but if you're getting shot at and they end up hitting glass, it will break.  (I am not able to retest this to confirm at the moment.)

Comment: This is correct. As far as mobs are concerned, all blocks are opaque.

Comment: @Raven except slab blocks.

Comment: @Nick And liquid source blocks…

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What about doors?

Comment: @chands I'm pretty sure doors are a special case. For one way they're special: They can be attacked through by mobs and player alike, but only from one side. Ghasts won't shoot through a door the 'wrong' way.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Very much so.

I have a large enclosed glass room in "Hell" (My mp netherworld) that stands over a great cavern with a lava lake beneath.

If there is a single hole in the room a ghast will fireball it and blast all the glass around you sending you spiraling into the lava below.

Without holes they don't shoot at the room though.

So the answer is hell yes--I died 3 times because of this!

Answer (score 1):

Ghasts can destroy glass although, can not see through glass, so as long as you stay in a glass tunnel or something along the lines of that you should be fine!